# Regular expression not excluding special character hyphen (-)

Tags: regex

I have a long text where I am supposed to *search for a 16 character word that starts with **c***

I wrote a regex as follows:

```
c[^\s\—][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-][^\s\-]
```

**But,**

it matches below 2 words

```
commodity—anythi
circumnavigation
```

I am learning regex but from what I know so far, **carat**`^` character should exclude **hyphen**`-` from my results, so I am unable to explain how `commodity—anythi` is showing up in my results?

I would appreciate if someone can explain me this behaviour. Thank you.

Comment: That's the only sign I have on my keyboard. I even tried doing `--` but to no avail.

Comment: I am using ReExr, an online Javascript Regex engine. This is the link to the website: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that out. For a moment I was sceptical about my concepts. If you want you can post your official answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: For some reason, my laptop does not have the hyphen. I only have to do it with a minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you have two characters here, a minus sign and a dash:
`—` is not equal to `-`. Additionally, consider using quantifiers:

```
c[^\s\—]+
```

See the [**comparison on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/GlwFhJ/1/).